# How to take photo with Google App Maker on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-app-maker

Do Google App Maker allows accessing Camera or Photos on iOS?

I'm considering the use of App maker in a browser or embedding App maker inside WebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Maker has a Google Drive widget that allows you to upload files to a Google Drive. On iOS it allows you to select photos from your library or to take a photo or video to upload.